# How do I translate "French is a difficult language for me to learn"?

Tags: grammaire

How do I translate

> French is a difficult language for me to learn.

?

I suspect that I don't know the grammar construction. Does this construction exist in French?

My attempt to translate it is below.

---

My attempt:

I already learned that "Do you want me to speak French?" uses two clauses (mini-sentences), and "que", and it does use a verb in the subjunctive.

I noticed that the sentence I'm having trouble translating also has a "me + infinitive". So I thought to try to use the same strategy:

"French is a difficult language for that I learn"???
("Le français est un langue difficile pour que j'appris"??)

I strongly suspect that this attempt is probably not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would generally be translated that way:

> Le français est une langue difficile pour moi.

but it is ambiguous. To specify the verb, you might say:

> Le français est une langue difficile à apprendre pour moi.

Comment: Given that the "me + infinitive" construction in "Do you want me to speak French" doesn't exist in French, I should have guessed that it also doesn't exist for "French is a difficult language for me to speak". I did not think of using "à + verb", so thanks!